# My subordinates keep my sanity in check

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> I’m neither a star nor a planet
>   But my subordinates surround me
>   They keep my sanity in check
>   If more were to join, I become pessimistic
>   If some were to leave I‘m overly optimistic

Who am I? Who are my subordinates?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> The nucleus of an atom.

Your subordinates are:

> Electrons

Sanity:

> The stability (sanity) of atoms depends on whether or not their outer-most shell is filled with electrons. Credit - marcellothearcane, in comments.

If more were to join:

> You would be negative.

If some were to leave:

> You would be positive.

Comment: (N flabalz bs fnavgl vf 'fgnovyvgl', naq vs gur bhgre furyy vf svyyrq jvgu ryrpgebaf, gur ngbz vf fgnoyr.) Could that be it?